# 'OR' search syntax

Tags: search, search-results

How can I search for organisations that share a part of the name (i.e. 'embassy of') but then add more attributes with `OR`? So, for example:

```
'embassy of' AND ('the US' OR 'the UK')
```

Answer (score 3):

(EDITED) You could use a combination of eg a smart group for Orgs with name contains 'embassy of', and then Tag every record that has 'the US', then search for contacts that are in Embassy group and US Tag and set 'search operator' to AND
"Search Operator
Determines whether your criteria are combined with AND statements, or combined with OR statements. For example, you may want to find all individuals who are in the Volunteers group AND who have a Volunteer Training activity recorded for them. In this case use the AND operator. If you need to find everyone who is in the Volunteers group OR has a Volunteer Training activity recorded, use the OR operator."

Comment: I presume the is for an Advanced Search.  If so, it won't work.  Although you can choose to  combine criteria in different fields with an AND or an OR, multiple selections for the same field (in this case the Group(s) field) are always combined with OR.  So this would return all organisations with "embassy of" in their name and also all organisations with "the US" in their name.

Comment: SO would it work if one was a Smart Group and the other a Tag? Obviously not a 'dynamic' solution but ...

Comment: Yes, that works, because they are different fields, so you can join them with AND or OR . AND is the default option, so if you have tagged "the embassy" and put "the US" and "the UK" into a smart group the result will be "the embassy of the US" and "the embassy of the UK".

Answer (score 2):

Try the search builder:

Include contacts where first name="john" and last name="doe"
+also include contacts where first name="john" and last name="coltrane"

should get you the list you want

Comment: Sorry, I should have asked a more precise question. What I really want to search is organisations that share a part of the name, i.e. 'embassy of' but then add more attributes with or - so 'embassy of' AND 'the US' or 'the UK'. Can't work that out using search builder.

Comment: You might edit your question then to improve this thread.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the revised question you should:

1. Use search builder to create a "countries of interest" (smart) group. "Also include contacts where" is the OR operator. I would suggest you specify % UK% and % US% etc as this will at least eliminate options where uk or us are in the centre of an organisation name.
2. Use search builder or advanced search to create a (smart) group for organisations with names like %embassy of%.
3. Use search builder to find the organisations in both groups then do with them what you will.